# Make first few rows unresponsive to slicer Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a data which looks like below:

```
  Brands  Sales Category Index
  Brand1    588        A     1
  Brand2    846        A     2
  Brand3    827        A     3
  Brand4    951        A     4
  Brand5    673        B     5
  Brand6    637        B     6
  Brand7    575        B     7
  Brand8    995        B     8
  Btand9    737        C     9
 Brand10    661        C    10
 Brand11    729        C    11
 Brand12    789        C    12
 Brand13    836        C    13
```

**Problem statement :**

I am trying to put Category as a slicer. However I want the rows for Category A to be present in the table view irrespective of the slicer which is selected.

**Example:** Lets say if Category B is selected in slicer , in this case the table should return all rows until Rank 8.

Below is an example of the desired output when category C is selected:

[image]

As you can see, the visual table has both Category A and Category C.

Similarly when both B and C are selected, I should be able to display all the categories (A,B and C).

What  tried:
I was thinking if we can use a conditional DAX which return 1 for selected values in slicers and mark rest as 0, I could use that as a visual filter and filter out 0. I tried various combinations of `Filter` with `in Filters` and `SELECTCOLUMN` but it did not work. Even the below measure returns all the rows instead of `Selected values|| category="A"`

```
test1 = CALCULATE(MIN('Table'[Index]),FILTER(ALLEXCEPT('Table','Table'[Brands]),'Table'[Category]=SELECTEDVALUE('Table'[Category]) || 'Table'[Category]="A"))
```

I also tried something like:

```
test = var cat = min('Table'[Category]) return IF(cat = SELECTEDVALUE('Table'[Category])||cat="A",1,0)
```

But this gives all as 1 , doesnot give 0 for rows which does not match the condition (note I have blocked the slicer interaction here)

[image]

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to separate your slicer table as keeping the value in the same table you can not achieve the requirement. You can create **custom table** with this below code-

> considering your base table name **sales**

> Lets create the custom table **category list**

> **No relation** can be there between table **sales** and **category list**

```
category list = 
SELECTCOLUMNS(
    sales,
    "Category",sales[Category]
)
```

Now, create the slicer using new custom table **category list** and create this below **Measure**-

```
is filter = 
if(
    MIN(sales[Category]) = "A",
    1,
    if (
        MIN(sales[Category]) IN VALUES('category list'[Category]),
        1,
        0
    )
)
```

Here below is a sample output when **C** selected-

[image]